# Clickatell getting routing error with Rest API

Tags: clickatell

When I try to send SMS to US number I'm getting from API accept but message not sent.
In clickatell I see "routing error"

Same message to number outside of US is working fine.

I have no 2-way number configured - is it a must?
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legislation in the US requires the use of a 2-way number if you are communicating via text with customers in this region. This is the likely cause of your routing error.

Hope this helps!